# Angular observable with ngFor

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, pipe, observable

I'm building a simple web application using angular. In my template i want to show a list of teachers.

From the server i'm getting this kind of `json()`

```
{ users : [{user1}, {user2}, {user3} ] }
```

this is my service file.

```
@Injectable()
export class StudentService {

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    getAllTeachers() {
        return this.http.get('https://guarded-beyond-19031.herokuapp.com/search');            
    }

}
```

Inside the controller i call `getAllTecher()` function. This is my controller file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from 'src/app/common/services/student.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-student',
  templateUrl: './home-student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-student.component.scss']
})
export class HomeStudentComponent implements OnInit {

  teachers$: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(
    private studentService: StudentService
  ) {
    this.teachers$ = this.studentService.getAllTeachers();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Inside of the html template i have use an `async` pipe. This is my template file.

```
<div *ngFor='let teacher of teachers| async'>
    {{teacher.name}}
</div>
```

But in my controller file, in this line

```
this.teachers$ = this.studentService.getAllTeachers();
```

i'm getting an error as given below.

```
Type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'Response'.
(property) HomeStudentComponent.teacherCards$: Observable<any[]>
```

whats the wrong with my code and how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [response](https://guarded-beyond-19031.herokuapp.com/search) is an object you need to use map operator in order to change the type of the result any use it in ngFor and just update the return type of `getAllTeachers` to `Observable<any[]>`

```
getAllTeachers() : Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http.get('https://guarded-beyond-19031.herokuapp.com/search')
         .pipe(map(result => result.user));            
 }
```

abd update teachers$ property to this way

```
  teachers$: Observable<any[]>;
```

Answer (score 1):

add return type for function

```
getAllTeachers(): Observable<Array<any>> {
```

Answer (score 1):

> The issue with response set of wrong type, you are assigning the object to array.

```
 getAllTeachers() {
        return this.http.get('https://guarded-beyond-19031.herokuapp.com/search')
       .pipe(map(response=>response["users"]))          
    }
```